do we need to add SharePoint indexes if we only want to filter SharePoint items through a power apps gallery?
I have a SharePoint test list named Test, and it contain 10,000 items and I did not add any index to the SharePoint list. Now when I write this formula, I were able to filter:-
Filter(Test,Num=Value(TextInput1.Text))

but when i wrote this formula to filter and sort, i did not get any item:-
Sort(Filter(Test,Num=Value(TextInput1.Text)),names)

so can i conclude that creating a SharePoint index is only needed for sorting and not for filtering? as seems the filter is working without having any index..
any advice?
